# Referencing information from same table in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have a geo table that contains

- countries
- localities (city, town, village, island, archipelago)
- locations (venue/business + boroughs/district/area),  e.g - Big Ben, or Southwark Borough.

For extra details of each place type, I have a relating tables.
'country_details' table for places of type 'country', and similarly for locations.

For a location like 'Big Ben', it has reference for the id of its locality (i.e London), and also reference to country (which can be simply by the country's iso_code)

Example:

```
 id |     title      |  locality_id  |  country_iso_code |
---------------------------------------------------------|
 1  | United Kingdom |     null      |     UK            |
 2  | London         |     null      |     UK            |
 3  | Big Ben        |      2        |     UK            |
 4  | XYZ District   |      2        |     UK            |
```

**Scenario**

Now, since in order to send the client information about Big Ben I'd also want to get to the name of locality (London) and the country (United Kingdom), it seems my only 2 options are:

1. recursive CTE
2. JOIN on the same table.

However, once we have a table of tens of thousand records, which can potentially grow into a lot more (few millions), aside for the query complexity it will also impact the performance I suppose.

**Question**

What is the better option to get "join" the details like "London" and "United Kingdom" ?
Are both options bad and it's better to rethink the schema design?

Tables :

```
CREATE TABLE places (
    id              int,
    type            smallint, -- ['country', 'locality', 'location']
    sub_type        smallint, -- nullable (city, village, etc.)

    -- names
    title           text,

    -- locality
    locality_name   text,
    locality_id     

    -- country
    country_iso_alpha2 text, -- 'GB'
    country_name       text, -- 'United Kingdom'
    admin_region       text, -- 'England', 'Texas', .. (null for Country)
    
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE country_details(
    place_id      int,
    place_type    smallint NOT NULL CHECK (item_type=1),

    iso_alpha2    text,
    iso_alpha3    text,
    ...

    PRIMARY KEY (place_id, place_type),
    FOREIGN KEY (place_id, place_type) references places (place_id, place_type) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE location_details(
    place_id      int,
    place_type    smallint NOT NULL CHECK (item_type=3),

    website            text,
    neighborhood       text,
    formatted_address  text,
    ...

    PRIMARY KEY (place_id, place_type),
    FOREIGN KEY (place_id, place_type) references places (place_id, place_type) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: The structure of the tables is not sufficiently understood
can you edit your question?